# Subtracting two dates in Dataframe returning days of difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need create a new column in a dataframe from pandas.
This column is a difference of date on dados["Vencimento Original"] and now. But my code below is returning an error.

Can you help me to solve this?

My code is:

```
dados["aging"] = dados["Vencimento Original"].sub(datetime.date, axis=0)
```

But returning

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'method_descriptor'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are `type(dados["aging"])` and `type(dados["Vencimento Original"].sub(satetime.date, axis=0))`?

Comment: Sorry, my question is in a bad format. How can i change? I change question, canyou change your vote of my question?

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to do math logic on datetime objects try
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html.
Be sure that all your columns are datetime objects

```
df.dtypes
```